# Javascript window.open not focusing in Windows7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm using IE8 in Windows7.  When in Javascript I do `window.open(....)`, the new window starts blinking in the taskbar.  I want the new window to be displayed to the user and not hide in the taskbar.

I've tried:

```
var myWindow = window.open(.....);
myWindow.focus();
```

But still it starts blinking in the taskbar.  Anyone knows the trick to fix this?

Comment: Nope. Not doable when the window is minimised

Comment: What about the other browsers and operating systems?  Do they do the same?  Which ones?

Comment: This web application only works in IE, so I can't really test in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this working.  Initially I was opening IE8 using the IE icon on the task bar menu.  For some reason I then decided to open IE directly from C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/ and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If there were a way to do what you want to do, every popup ad in the world would use it and the web would be a worse place.  so there isn't a way to do it.  =)

You might have better luck if the window.open occurs in a click handler or something like it - there are complicated heuristics baked into the browser around allowing poups if they're deemed 'intentional'.